# Trying to run python code from repo without instructions

Tags: python

I am trying to run a code from [this repo](https://github.com/gkaradzhov/FactcheckingRANLP) without success. There are no instructions on how to run it. I suspect I should run `FactcheckingRANLP/Factchecking_clean/classification/lstm_train.py` and then run `.../lstm_test.py`.

The problem is that this code uses `import` statements as a module, referencing to folders and files that are in different directories, for example, in `lstm_train.py`:

```
File "lstm_train.py", line 3, in <module>
    from classification.lstm_utils import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'classification'
```

This is the tree structure of the classification folder:

```
.
├── classification
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── lstm_repres.py
│   ├── lstm_test.py
│   ├── lstm_train.py
│   ├── lstm_train.pyc
│   ├── lstm_utils.py
│   ├── lstm_utils.pyc
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── lstm_train.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   └── lstm_utils.cpython-36.pyc
│   └── svm_run.py
```

**I would like to know how can I make python run lsmt_train/test.py files in such a manner that the import statements contained within them are compiled correctly.** I prefer not to modify the code as this could possibly generate a lot of errors..

Answer (score 1):

You could add the path pointing to the classification folder to your python path variable.

I suggest using the sys package:

```
import sys

sys.path.append('<<<PathToRepo>>>/FactcheckingRANLP/Factchecking_clean')
```

With the repo classification directory added to your python path, the import statements should work.

EDIT:
Correction; in the initial post I suggested adding the path to .../classification to your path variable, instead the parent folder .../Factchecking_clean is required as the file imports the module 'classification'.

Also, in Lucas Azevedo's answer, the parent directory path is added in the repository lstm_train file itself. While this definitely works, I still think it should be possible without editing the original repository.

I took a look at the repo in question and files like lstm_train.py are scripts which should be executed with the python working directory set as `'<<<PathToRepo>>>/FactcheckingRANLP/Factchecking_clean'`.

There are a few ways to do so:

1. You could open the project in a python IDE and configure your execution to use the directory `.../Factchecking_clean` as the working directory. In pycharm for example this could be done by importing the repo directory `.../Factchecking_clean` as a project. The following image shows how to set a working directory for execution in pycharm:

[image]

I think the repository was developed with this execution configuration set up.

2. Another possibility is to execute the python script from within another python file. This seems to be rather inconvenient to me, regardless you could do so by creating a separate python file with:

```
import sys
import os

sys.path.append('<<<PathToRepo>>>/FactcheckingRANLP/Factchecking_clean')
os.chdir('<<<PathToRepo>>>/FactcheckingRANLP/Factchecking_clean')
exec(open('./classification/lstm_train.py').read())
```

This adds the `Factchecking_clean` directory to the python path (using `sys.path.append()`) to be able to import stuff like `classification.utils`. The working directory is set by `os.chdir()` and finally `exec(open('<<<filepath>>>')).read()` executes the lstm_train file with the correct working directory and path variable set up.

Executing the new python file with the code above works for me (without editing the original repository).

However, as scripts like lstm_train.py actually are used to execute specific parts of the code provided in the rest of the repository modules, I think editing these files for experimental purposes is fine. In general, when working with repositories like this I recommend using an IDE (like pycharm) with a correctly set up configuration (method 1).

Comment: Added the snipped you've suggested to `lstm_train.py`, even though not wanting to modify the repo's code and still got errors:

`from classification.lstm_utils import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'classification'`

Comment: Ah, sorry for the confusion, I missed the fact that the module 'classification' is imported instead of the lstm_utils file. You spotted this yourself, but I'll edit my answer to prevent confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up having to modify the repository's code, following the suggestion of Jeff.

```
import sys,os
parent_dir_path = os.path.abspath(__file__+"/../..")
sys.path.append(parent_dir_path)
```

adding the path until `classification` doesnt work, as the import is done mentioning the `classification` folder. The parent directory is the one that has to be added.

`__file__` gives the current file name and `os.path.abspath` resolves the path navigation done with `/../..`